# Is patent EP2382885 awarded or pending?

Tags: filing, european, ep2382885

[A foldable footwear, EP2382885 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/EP2382885A1?cl=en)

Is this patent awarded or pending? If it is pending, how long will it be before a decision is issued?

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be derived from [the register of European patents](https://register.epo.org/espacenet/regviewer). It tells you that examination was requested in March, and that in May the applicant filed amended claims (and thus the application is still pending). Further, if you click on the 'all documents' tab in the left upper corner of the page, you will be directed to the file itself where you can view or download al documents from the file.

It is impossible to tell how long it will take before a decision is issued. First of all, how soon the Examiner will take up the file and issue the first Office Action will depend on their workload; and then how long it will take before the application is accepted or refused will depend on the nature of the claims and the objections against those claims.

Comment: Probably also worth noting the US counterpart, publication number: US2012079745.